# Functions with domains

Tags: functions

I have the following question:

> $3$. The functions $f$ and $g$ are defined with their respective domains by: $$f(x)=x^3,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$$ $$g(x)=\frac{1}{x-3},\quad x\in\mathbb{R},\:\:x\ne3$$
>   a)$\quad\:\:$State the range of $f$.
>
> b)$\quad\:\:$i)$\quad\:\:$ Find $fg(x)$.
>
> $\qquad\,\,$ii)$\quad\:$ Solve the equation $fg(x)=64$.
>
> c)$\quad\:\:$i)$\quad\:\:$ The inverse of $g(x)$ is $g^{-1}(x)$. Find $g^{-1}(x)$.
>
> $\qquad\,\,$ii)$\quad\:$ State the range of $g^{-1}(x)$.

Here is my attempt. Are my answers correct?

> Let $f(x)=x^3,\:x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-3},\:x\in\mathbb{R},\:x\ne3$.
>
> a)$\quad\:\:$ The set $\{f(x)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is called the range of $f$, and it is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> b)$\quad\:\:$ $f(x)=x^3$ is a polynomial and $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-3}$.
>
> $\qquad\,\,$ i)$\quad\:\:$ $f(g(x))=f\left(\dfrac{1}{x-3}\right)=\left(\dfrac{1}{x-3}\right)^3=\dfrac{1}{(x-3)^3}$
>
> $\qquad\,\,$ii)$\quad\:$ $f(g(x))=64$
>
> $\qquad\qquad\dfrac{1}{(x-3)^3}=64$
>
> $\qquad\qquad\quad\;\dfrac{1}{x-3}=4$
>
> $\qquad\qquad\quad\:\,\,x-3=\dfrac{1}{4}$
>
> $\qquad\qquad\:\:4(x-3)=1$
>
> $\qquad\qquad\:\:\,4x-12=1$
>
> $\hspace{31mm} 4x=13$
>
> $\hspace{33mm} x=\dfrac{13}{4}$
>
> c)$\quad\:\:\:$i)$\quad\:\:$ Let $g(x)=y$. Then $x=g^{-1}(y)$.
>
> $\hspace{24mm} \dfrac{1}{x-3}=y$
>
> $\hspace{26mm} x-3=\dfrac{1}{y}$
>
> $\hspace{33.5mm} x=\dfrac{1}{y}+3$
>
> $\hspace{33.5mm} x=\dfrac{1+3y}{y}$
>
> $\hspace{24mm} g^{-1}(y)=\dfrac{1+3y}{y}$
>
> $\hspace{21mm}$ Now we can change variables:
>
> $\hspace{24mm} g^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{1+3x}{x}$
>
> $\qquad\,\,$ii)$\quad\:$ The set $\{g^{-1}(x)\mid x\in\mathbb{R},\:x\ne0\}$ is called the range of $g^{-1}(x)$, and it is equal to the $\hspace{20mm}$ domain of $g(x)$; i.e., the range of $g^{-1}(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{3\}$.

Comment: Yeah that looks good.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

If part b) had said $f(g(x))$, I would be inclined to say your answers are all correct. In fact, it says $fg(x)$, which is usually taken to mean $f(x)\times g(x)$ and is sometimes written as $(f\times g)(x)$. In this case, $fg(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{x-3}$, and the resulting equation, $fg(x)=64$, doesn't look that difficult to solve. The rest of your answers are exactly right, though!